# Creating a new variable based on conditions of 3 other variables in R

Tags: r

I have a data set (n=500) in R that looks like this

```
ID    A      C      S
1     4      4      4 
2     3      2      3
3     5      4      2
```

Id like to create a new variable(I am calling this variable "same")  that tells me whether any of my columns have the same value (excluding my ID column). So,

```
ID    A      C      S     Same
1     4      4      4     all
2     3      2      3     as
3     5      4      2     none
4     7      7      2     ac
```

Any help would be much appreciated! I am pretty lost! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may loop over the rows with `apply` (`MARGIN = 1`) with selected columns (`[-1]` without the 'ID' column), then check the `length` of `unique` elements, `if` it is 1, return 'all' or `else` `paste` the `names` of the `duplicated` elements.  If there are no duplicates, then it returns blank `""`, change the blank to 'none'

```
df1$Same <- apply(df1[-1], 1, \(x) {
    x1 <- if(length(unique(x)) == 1) 'all' else 
  paste(tolower(names(x))[duplicated(x)|duplicated(x,
    fromLast = TRUE)], collapse = "")
    x1[x1 == ""] <- "none"
  x1})
```

-output

```
> df1
  ID A C S Same
1  1 4 4 4  all
2  2 3 2 3   as
3  3 5 4 2 none
4  4 7 7 2   ac
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, A = c(4L, 3L, 5L, 7L), C = c(4L, 2L, 
4L, 7L), S = c(4L, 3L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `dplyr` `rowwise` with `rle`

```
df |> rowwise() |> mutate(Same = case_when(length(rle(sort(c_across(A:S)))$values) == 1 ~ "all" ,
length(rle(sort(c_across(A:S)))$values) == 3 ~ "none" ,
c_across(A) == c_across(C) ~ "ac" ,
c_across(C) == c_across(S) ~ "cs" , TRUE ~ "as"))
```

- output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 5
# Rowwise: 
     ID     A     C     S Same 
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>
1     1     4     4     4 all  
2     2     3     2     3 as   
3     3     5     4     2 none 
4     4     7     7     2 ac
```